# how to remove questions from being on hold even after fixing a question?

Tags: support

Many times question is put on hold for not being specific or for other reasons. It is mentioned that, if we fix the question such that it fits all the guidelines, the question could be taken off hold.

But even after fixing the question, it is not taken off hold. What can we do in such a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes 5 votes by community members to reopen a question after editing, and that can take some time as it goes through the review queue. I found one of your questions that had 4 reopen votes on it, so I went ahead and cast the last vote.

There is more information about reopening questions in the Help Center article [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

You did exactly the right thing - you edited the question to address the concerns, and when it was taking a long time to get reopened, you posted on meta to draw the community's attention to it.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to flag your own question. So, after your edit, you could simply flag it, along with a comment that goes something like this:

> I've edited my question and hope it can now be reopened.

I'm not sure which might come first: five votes from community members, or a moderator handling the flag. It mostly depends on who is around, and what they are doing. But flagging it might speed up the process.